# How do I inject CDI beans into custom entity classes?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi, wildfly

We use Cassandra (and the DataStax driver) to store our entities. As such we have a custom entity service that creates new instances of our entity classes when it retrieves data from Cassandra.

I also need to inject services into my entity classes using CDI. How do I do this? When I simply at the @Inject annotation, it never gets injected.

```
public class Customer{

    @Inject
    private Event<DeactivationEvent> events;

    private String uid;

    public void setUid(String uid){
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUid(){
        return this.uid;
    }

    public void deactivate(){

        events.fire( new DeactivationEvent() );

    }

}


public CassandraEntityService{

    public static Customer findCustomer(String uid){

        ...whatever lookup logic...
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.setUid(..)
        customer.set...

        return customer;

    }

}
```

For reference, I'm using JBoss/Wildfly 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem in `CassandraEntityService.findCustomer()` is that the `Customer` instance is not a CDI bean, because `findCustomer` calls the constructor directly.

You might run into trouble using [entities as CDI beans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520220/14379), but I think (a) you need a producer method for the `Customer`, and (b) `CassandraEntityService` itself needs to be another bean which `@Inject`s the `Customer`, instead of calling the constructor directly.

However, a better solution for the more general problem (firing an event when the entity changes) would probably be an [Entity Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749132/14379), in which case `Customer` probably won't have any need to be a CDI bean.